# How do I check the tag of a GameObject when I collide with it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, tags, collision

My code is:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag ("bullet"))
        {
            UI.lives--;
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "life")
        {
            UI.livePart++;
        }
    }
```

I've tried two different methods of making it work and neither actually function correctly.
For the top one, when my player object first collides with a gameObject with the tag "bullet", it should decrease my "lives" integer by 1.

For the second one, it should increase another integer "livePart" by 1 when it first collides with a gameObject with the tag "life".

UI is the code that is storing the variables "lives" and "livePart".

Comment: did you have add Collider Component ?

Comment: @TimChang yes they all have colliders.

Comment: Have you checked that `OnCollisionEnter ( ... )` is actually getting called and `isTrigger` is not selected on the `Collider` component!!!! If these checks are performed correctly, then it appears the first `if clause` is the best way to go about it :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw do I need a rigid body for the collider to work? if not then it should be colliding. none of them are set to triggers.

Comment: @CocoWaff: At least one of the colliding gameobjects need to have a `Rigidbody. Look for the description part of [Collider.OnCollisionEnter ( ... )](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) doc.

Comment: @nIcEcOw the object using this script is a rigid body, the mess up seems to be happening in the script, not the colliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to check for is that the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) mentions

> Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.

If you happen to have "Is Kinematic" checked in the inspector under RigidBody, then you will not get collision events.

Also, just in case this is new information, attaching a debugger to your scripts as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjNDXKgbhgY) can really help. For example you can set a break point in the `OnCollisionEnter` funtion to verify that it is ever getting called.

Comment: My gameObject is Dynamic and thanks for pointing out the break point tool, it turns out that my OnCollisionEnter function isn't even being called. though I cannot understand why. any tips as to why it might not be called? all of my objects have colliders, and the colliders on the object being hit work perfectly.

I'll probably delete this question later since it seems that I was focusing on the wrong part of the issue the whole time.

Comment: Also I would recommend using CompareTag as its more efficient

Comment: any chance you could share the project or a small sample with same setup?

Comment: Hey @CocoWaff! Maybe you could try to increase the size of the collider to check if it finally calls OnCollisionEnter.
I had the same issue on a project and the clue I have is that the collision happens between 2 frames or something like that which does not trigger the event.

hope it might help you!

Answer (score 0):

If all your objects have sufficiently sized colliders and are still not getting collisions. Ensure that your objects also have a RigidBody component. And as @Matt Brown has said, ensure that the "Is Kinematic" toggle box is set to off.